# Как в имя документа добавить время потраченное на его создание?

Tags: c#

Вопрос:
Как в имя создаваемого документа, вставить время потраченное на его создание?

```
string fileName = "prefix" + "_" + "время создания документа в формате ЧЧММССННН: ЧЧ" + "" + "_" + 

                           string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateTime.Now) + ".xml";
```

Comment: ":" - этот знак запрещен в пути, используйте "_"

Comment: Вообще то я просто подчеркнул где должно располагаться время создания файла. Про то что нельзя использовать ":"  прекрасно знаю.

Comment: [Форматный вывод даты](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Прочти вопрос раз десять, чтоб понять его. Речь вообще не о формате времени ))). Речь о том как в имя создаваемого документа, вставить время потраченное на его создание.

Comment: Не надо хамить, лучше напишите это явно в вопросе, ибо я его прочитал три раза - там только "время создание документа", что на русском не расшифровывается однозначно.

Comment: Извиняюсь, но в вопросе не было указано "Почему не работает код" и как задать формат даты. Просто уйма времени на гугл уже потратил и первый раз такое тех задание встречаю )))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Запускаем таймер
Stopwatch makeFile = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// Создаем временный файл
string tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

// Что-то с ним делаем
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tmpFile))
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
     {
          sw.WriteLine(i.ToString());
     }
}

// Останавливаем таймер        
makeFile.Stop();

// Берем полученный интервал времени (время затраченное на создание)
TimeSpan ts = makeFile.Elapsed;

// Дата создания файла
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

// Имя файла с временем, затраченным на создание
string fileName1 = string.Format(@"C:\Users\admin\Documents\NewFile_{0:D2}-{1:D2}-{2:D2}_{3:D2}.txt", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);

// Имя файла с временем создания
string fileName2 = string.Format(@"C:\Users\admin\Documents\NewFile_{0:D2}-{1:D2}-{2:D2}_{3:D2}.txt", dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, dt.Millisecond);

// Перемещаем и переименовываем временный файл
File.Move(tmpFile, fileName1);
// File.Move(tmpFile, fileName2);
```